# How to render tags for the Amiga Workbench? Include or exclude the version number?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is already a question using the tag `workbench1.3`:
[Change Amiga Shell keyboard layout in Workbench 1.3](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/113/change-amiga-shell-keyboard-layout-in-workbench-1-3)

(Yes, the tag in the current form would likely have to be changed to `workbench-1.3`, but that's not that important for this discussion.)

There were different Versions of the Amiga Workbench, for instance *Workbench 1.2*, *Workbench 1.3*, *Workbench 2.0*, *Workbench 2.1* and so on.

Does it make sense to have corresponding specific tags `workbench-1.3`, `workbench-2.0`, etc.? Is such a specific tag when searching for workbench related questions necessary? There are substantial differences between the major versions and noticeable, but often smaller differences between the minor versions, but does it justify having separate tags for them?

Maybe a general tag `workbench` suffices?

Also, while *Workbench* in a retrocomputing context can probably only refer to the Amiga Workbench, one might like to have it specifically prefixed like that: `amiga-workbench`. However, that is likely unnecessary, as questions regarding the Workbench would usually be tagged with `amiga` as well.

Which style of tagging for the Amiga Workbench would you prefer and what is the rationale for your choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be worth having both version-specific *and* generic tags for the Workbench. I'm modelling it from SO, where we have a [python](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag as well as [python-3.x](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), [python-2.7](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

Questions about the Workbench series *in general* should be using the [amiga-workbench](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amiga-workbench) tag (or just [workbench](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workbench), though I think the former is clearer). Questions that only pertain to a specific model should use that model's tag (for example, problems that only happened with one model, or specific types of hardware each model used).

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion. Also, if the a tag `amiga-workbench` (as opposed to just `workbench`) makes it more clear what is referred, I'm fine with that. `amiga-workbench` could be the master tag and `workbench` could be a synonym tag.

Comment: What about the tags that include the version number? Would the master tag be `amiga-workbench-1.3` or `workbench-1.3`?

Comment: @blubberdiblub We might as well include `amiga`, since there's space for it.

Comment: Agree that there should be a generic and a version specific tag. How specific should they be? Ie. we should have workbench, 1.3 or 1.x, 2.0 and 3.0 at least, but would it make sense to also have 3.1 or should one just specify in the question that it is version 3.1 and use the workbench-3 tag?

Comment: I think if you are going to have version specific tags, they need to be inclusive of the major releases, so there would be `amiga-workbench-3.0`, `amiga-workbench-3.1` and `amiga-workbench-3.9`

Answer (score 2):

Why "Workbench"? The Amiga operating system was made by two components, Workbench and Kickstart, that really was meant to run in only some combinations (namely, the major version of the two should match). Moreover somewhat later in the life of the machine, the combination of the two were called "AmigaOS".

So I propose: `amigaos-1.x`, `amigaos-2.x`, `amigaos-3.x`, `amigaos-3.5`, `amigaos-3.9`, `amigaos-4.x`, the latter three if we also want to talk about non-historical versions made after Commodore went bankrupt.